# DotNetNuke MVC routing conflict

Tags: model-view-controller, routes, dotnetnuke

I have a number of DotNetNuke MVC modules that are configured like the following:

RouterConfig

```
    namespace IMT.LH.AssociationAdmin
    {
    using System;
    using DotNetNuke.Web.Mvc.Routing;
    public class RouteConfig : IMvcRouteMapper
    {
        public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
        {
            mapRouteManager.MapRoute(
                moduleFolderName: "LH.AssociationAdmin",
                routeName: "LH.AssociationAdmin",
                url: "{controller}/{action}",
                namespaces: new[] {"IMT.LH.AssociationAdmin.Controllers"});
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
namespace IMT.LH.AssociationAdmin.Controllers
{
    [DnnHandleError]
    public class AssociationController : DnnController
    {

        [ModuleAction(ControlKey = "Display", TitleKey = "DisplayOrganization")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DotNetNuke.Framework.JavaScriptLibraries.JavaScript.RequestRegistration(CommonJs.DnnPlugins);

            var Associations = new IMS.Model.lh.AssociationsController().Gets().Recordset;
            var AssociationSelectList =
                from c in Associations
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Selected = false,
                    Text = c.Title,
                    Value = c.AssociationID.ToString()
                };
            var tlist = AssociationSelectList.ToList();
            tlist.Insert(0,new SelectListItem{Selected=true,Text=@"Create...",Value="-1"});

            ViewBag.SelectAssociation = new SelectList(tlist, "Value", "Text", -1);
            return View("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [DotNetNuke.Web.Mvc.Framework.ActionFilters.ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult SelectAssociation()
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            var id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["id"]);
            using (var ac = new AssociationsController())
            {
                ac.GetById(id);
                return Json(ac.CurrentRec);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works great on all the modules. I have ajax post statements that work as expected:

```
$.ajax({
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/DesktopModules/MVC/LH.AssociationAdmin/Association/SaveEdits",
            method: "Post",
```

We just bought an off-the-shelf shopping cart. When I installed it, it is returning an error. After talking to the vendor, they said:

the issue is basically a redirect from "/DesktopModules/RazorCart/AdminConsole" to "/DesktopModules/MVC/LH.AssociationAdmin" caused by a registered route in "IMT.LH.AssociationAdmin.RouteConfig"
You have a module called "LH.AssociationAdmin" and the assembly file is "LH.AssociationAdmin.dll". This is an MVC model and with DNN MVC, modules should register their routes through the module definition controls, which this module is doing but it also registers another route through "IMvcRouteMapper", I understand that modules also needs APIs, but this should be done using "IServiceRouteMapper"

I tried to convert my routes to IServiceRouterMapper:

```
using DotNetNuke.Web.Api;
    public class RouteMapper : IServiceRouteMapper
    {
        public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
        {
            mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute("LH.AssociationAdmin", "LH.AssociationAdmin", "{controller}/{action}", new[] {"IMT.LH.AssociationAdmin.Controllers"});
        }
    }
```

However, my post commands no longer worked. I then tried changing the base class in the controller to DnnApiController but then I couldn't use ViewBag, Request.Form and some other methods.

How do I make all this work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This was a matter of conflicting routes. My modules accounted for it. There's did not. So, I created a route in each of my modules that would not conflict with the third-party software. To whit:

```
public class RouteConfig : IMvcRouteMapper
{
    public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
    {
                mapRouteManager.MapRoute(

                    "LH.AssociationAdmin", 
                    "LH.AssociationAdmin", 
                    "{controller}/{action}/{IMTAssociationAdminId}",
                    new[] {"IMT.LH.AssociationAdmin.Controllers"});
    }
}
```

In this case, I added a dummy parameter called IMTAssocationAdminId and the ajax looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "/DesktopModules/MVC/LH.AssociationAdmin/Association/SelectAssociation/xxx",
                method: "Post",
                data: {
                    AssociationId: $(this).val()
                },
                headers: {
                    "ModuleId": moduleId,
                    "TabId": tabId,
                    "RequestVerificationToken": rvtoken
                },...
```

The /xxx is just a dummy parameter associated with {IMTAssociationAdminId}.